# Unix how to store fuser command output to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, fuser

I'm a newbie in scripting and I have this problem:

I want to use the `fuser` command to check if a file with that name is present. I want to save the output of the command and later use it to rename the file before loading.

I have tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name='test'
echo 'file_name before: '$file_name
file_name=`fuser FILE_DIR/SD/Test_file_??????????????.dat`
echo 'file_name after: '$file_name'
```

However, the result of the above code is:

```
-bash-3.00$ script.sh
file_name before :test
FILE_DIR/SD/Test_file_20180823120345.dat
file_name after:
```

The output of the command is not getting stored in variable but getting displayed in screen and I can't figure out why!

What I want to do is to store `Test_file_20180823120345.dat` in the  `file_name` variable, and then remove the timestamp from that and rename the file to `Test_file_20180823.dat`.

Then after loading the data in the staging table again rename the file to the old file name that we have received and then archive the file with its original name.

Comment: When posting a question related to *bash*, it helps to add the `bash` tag. POSIX shell lacks many features found in bash, so you are likely to get more fitting answer if you add the tag for your shell. The `#!/bin/bash` tells me you are actually using bash instead of POSIX shell.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems is a missing closing single quote in:

```
echo 'file_name before: '$file_name
```

(which is also why you had to unbalance the quotes in `echo 'file_name after: '$file_name'` on the last line to get the script to run)

Instead, simply double-quote the entire string for `echo` that will allow expansion of your variable `file_name`, e.g.

```
echo "file_name after: $file_name"
```

Further, avoid using backticks for *command substitution*, instead use the `$(...)` form, e.g.

```
file_name=$(fuser FILE_DIR/SD/Test_file_??????????????.dat)
```

Or re-written it could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name='test'
echo "file_name before: $file_name"
file_name=$(fuser FILE_DIR/SD/Test_file_??????????????.dat)
echo "file_name after: $file_name"
```

(**note:** your matching with `fuser` will only match a pattern with `14` characters after `Test_file_` followed by `.dat` -- which may be what you want, but it can probably be written in a cleaner way depending on the possibilities of `??????????????`)

While `fuser` will provide an error, you may also want to get in the habit of *validating* that your command substitution returned a variable by testing whether `file_name` is empty after the call to `fuser`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name='test'
echo "file_name before: $file_name"
file_name=$(fuser FILE_DIR/SD/Test_file_??????????????.dat)
if [ -z "$file_name" ]; then
    echo "error: no file matched pattern" >&2
else
    echo "file_name after: $file_name"
fi
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi David,       Thanks for the response...   But when i put the fuser command in brackets i am getting illegal variable name error

Comment: Is there any other command to find out a file with the specific pattern and store it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks David, my work is done.  I am using find instead of fuser..once again thanks for your response and time

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Sorry I missed your earlier comments. `find` is a great way to go. Good luck with your scripting.